# truepush callback reading

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

I have the following object:
[object via console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzobO.png).
And with the following code, I get it and read it.

```
    truepush.push({
  operation: "get-tags",
  callback: function(error,response){
               console.log(error,response);

               subscribedTopics = [];
               response.data.forEach(el => subscribedTopics.push(el.name));

               console.log("SUBSCRIBED LIST: " + subscribedTopics);

               subscribedTopics.forEach(function(el) {
                 if (el.name.equals("choir")) {
                   console.log("CHOIR CALLED");
                 }
                 else if (el.name.equals("kobel")) {
                   console.log("KOBEL CALLED");
                 }
                 else if (el.name.equals("kitchen")) {
                   console.log("KITCHEN CALLED");
                 }
               });
             }
  });
```

But I get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at callback (index.js:1869)
at main.js:1
at XMLHttpRequest.i.onreadystatechange (main.js:1)
```

It says the error is in this line:

```
response.data.forEach(el => subscribedTopics.push(el.name));
```

What's the problem here?

**EDIT:**
This is what I get when I run: `console.log(response);`
[image: console result]

**EDIT 2:**
The weired thing: When I print the subscribedTopics array (as you can see above in the code example)....

```
console.log("SUBSCRIBED LIST: " + subscribedTopics);
```

...it returns the right array I expect. ["choir", "kobel", "kitchen"]

**EDIT 3:**
With following code I found out something weired:

```
truepush.push({
  operation: "get-tags",
  callback: function(error,response){
               console.log("______________________");
               console.log("full output of console.log(error, response.data):");
               console.log(error, response.data);
               console.log("______________________");

               subscribedTopics = [];
               response.data.forEach(el => subscribedTopics.push(el.name));

               subscribedTopics.forEach(function(el) {
                 if (el.name.equals("choir")) {
                   console.log("CHOIR CALLED");
                   document.getElementById("switch_choir").checked = true;
                 }
                 else if (el.name.equals("kobel")) {
                   console.log("KOBEL CALLED");
                   document.getElementById("switch_kobel").checked = true;
                 }
                 else if (el.name.equals("kitchen")) {
                   console.log("KITCHEN CALLED");
                   document.getElementById("switch_kitchen").checked = true;
                 }
               });
             }
  });
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]
**Seems like the callback fires two times. First with the correct object and than when it fires the secound time its undefined.**

~Filip

Comment: Just to confirm, are you passing in all the correct parameters? And is the onreadystatechange at the right state?

Comment: `response.data` is the thing that's undefined here.  In other words your response object has no `data` property

Comment: @James Yes, but why?

Comment: @ThomasBui What you mean with is the onreadystatechange  is at the right state?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(error, response)`?

Comment: Is `truepush` from a well-known library?  If so, can you link it?  Otherwise if it's your own library please post the code.

Comment: @Molda Please have a look at my edit:)

Comment: @James Yes, its public. Its for sending push notification for free for the web: https://www.truepush.com/

Comment: To me it sounds like callback is being executed at the wrong time.  I don't see any documentation that might indicate how to do it a better way.

Comment: @FilipDegenhart So the code you are showing us has no issues. The problem seem to be in the callback being called twice. You haven't provided any code regarding the calling of the callback, so there's no way to help you. I haven't found any docs for the truepush either. Simplest solution although maybe not ideal is `if(!response) return;`

Comment: @Molda Thats the problem. Thats all code I have. Thats all. I only have an initialization of truepush, but nothing more. So the push function of truepush automaticlly set up a callback.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
if(response.data !== 'undefined'){
    response.data.forEach(el => subscribedTopics.push(el.name));
}
```

Comment: Throws back "Uncaught TypeError: response.forEach is not a function". And there is a nother weired thing, you find in my edit 2

Comment: What is the output of console.log(error, response.data)?

Comment: Seems like the callback fires two times. First with the correct object and than when it fires the second time its undefined. If i where you i would debug and try to find out why it fires two times and not one and what does the second is the second response

Comment: That sounds logical, but it does not work. The console returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" for the same line

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, and the responses you're getting, it doesn't look like it should do that. In fact, if you're getting to the line:

`console.log("SUBSCRIBED LIST: " + subscribedTopics);`

then you couldn't have failed on `response.data.forEach`.

This leads me to believe that maybe this function is running twice - once where you're getting the data prop, and maybe once when you don't

Comment: We found that out yesterday too. But whta I should going to do to fix my problem?

Comment: That is difficult to determine without knowing the API/documentatioun for `truepush` or the preceding code that is invoking it. I would put a breakpoint in the code to determine when it is being called, to see why this code is being called twice.